# ReactJS none minified erros in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

Situation: My application is currently under development but I have a separated demosystem which uses the build version of my product for demonstration purpose for potential customers and general interested users. My project has a very high ordered Error-Boundary component to catch unhandeled exceptions which allows me to avoid ugly application-crashes. Instead of a normal crash a well formatted error-page will be shown which contains the error message occured combined with the stack-trace.

I just realised that in production (after `npm run build`) the error and even stack-trace is highly minified and does not allow me to recognize the exact problem-causing piece of code (e.g. stacktrace is not clearly readable anymore) were the problem occurred and also some customers cannot explain me what they did to get the problem.

Is there any way to reproduce the stack-trace original named variables with any kind of translation-table or an option to get full error messages even after the

```
npm build
```

Edit: Fixed typos and made problem easier to understand.

Comment: do you know how to reproduce a bag? If yes - could you reproduce it on localhost? If no,as far as I see the only option is to switch off minification/uglification in your bundler (webpack I suppose), then deploy it on production(if it isn't in use at that moment) then check stack trace. When stack trace is checked deploy on prod usual minified version

Comment: You can use source map which can help you in stack trace and error line

Comment: @DmitriySakhno can you please ellaborate how to switch of the minification/uglification?

Comment: if you use webpack try this https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/

Comment: and read this https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production hidden-source-map sounds like your option

Answer (score 2):

you can **eject** your ceate-create-app and change optimization inside **config/webpack.config.js**:

```js
    optimization: {
      minimize:  isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        // This is only used in production mode
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
```

just change minimize to **true**

or you can generate two builds of application one development and one production.

serve development build if user is admin e.g.

Comment: Hello Armin, thanks you for the clarification and problem solving. There is your reward :)